# Evaluate variable before passing to JSP Tag Handler

Tags: java, jsp, jsp-tags

When trying to use a custom JSP tag library, I have a variable defined in JSP that I would like to be evaluated before being passed to the tag library. However, I cannot seem to get it to work. Here's a simplified version of my JSP:

```
<% int index = 8; %>

<foo:myTag myAttribute="something_<%= index %>"/>
```

The `doStartTag()` method of my `TagHandler` uses the pageContext's output stream to write based on the inputted attribute:

```
public int doStartTag() {
    ...
    out.println("Foo: " + this.myAttribute);
}
```

However, the output I see in my final markup is:

```
Foo: something_<%= index %>
```

instead of what I want:

```
Foo: something_8
```

My tag library definition for the attribute is:

```
<attribute>
    <name>myAttribute</name>
    <required>true</required>
</attribute>
```

I have tried to configure the attribute with `rtexprvalue` both `true` and `false`, but neither worked. Is there a way I can configure the attribute so that it's evaluated before being sent to the Handler? Or am I going about this totally wrong?

I'm relatively new to JSP tags, so I'm open to alternatives for solving this problem. Also, I realize that using scriptlets in JSP is frowned upon, but I'm working with some legacy code here so I'm kind of stuck with it for now.

**Edit:**

I have also tried:

```
<foo:myTag myAttribute="something_${index}"/>
```

which does not work either - it just outputs `something_${index}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't believe that you can use a `<%= ... %>` within an attribute in a custom tag, unless your `<%= ... %>` is the entire contents of the attribute value.  Does the following work for you?

```
<% int index = 8; %>
<% String attribValue = "something_" + index; %>

<foo:myTag myAttribute="<%= attribValue %>"/>
```

EDIT: I believe the `<% ... %>` within the custom tag attribute can only contain a variable name. not any Java expression.

Answer (score 2):

To keep your JSP code clean and neat, avoid scripting when possible. I think this is the preferred way to do it:

```
<foo:myTag >
  <jsp:attribute name="myAttribute">
    something_${index}
  </jsp:attribute>
</foo:myTag >
```

if your tag also contains a body, you'll have to change it from

```
<foo:myTag myAttribute="<%= attribValue %>">
  body
</foo:myTag >
```

to

```
<foo:myTag >
  <jsp:attribute name="myAttribute">
    something_${index}
  </jsp:attribute>
  <jsp:body>
    body
  </jsp:body>
</foo:myTag >
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this reminder. I never found this in the JSP taglib tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

`<foo:myTag myAttribute="something_${index}"/>`

Comment: I've actually tried that as well, and it didn't work for me either. I'll update the question - but thanks for the answer.